# visual studio 2017 solution debug error

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Friday I have installed VS2017 on my machine. I opened a test project and hit F5. Luckily enough I keep getting this error.

The program '[5548] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).
The program '[5548] dotnet.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

No debug, no running...

Thanks